# Multiple Endpoints may not be deployed using the same path

Tags: jakarta-ee, websocket, chat

I was trying to make the simple chat project with two users

but I'm getting the exception as

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.websocket.DeploymentException: Multiple Endpoints may not be deployed to using the same path [/websocket]
```

in catalina.out

Here is my source file content

```
   @ServerEndpoint("/websocket")
    public class ChatEndPoint {

        @OnMessage
        public void message(String message, Session session) throws IOException, EncodeException {
            //processed the message
        }
   }
```

I was running the project on server from eclipse kepler, with oracle java 7 on ubuntu 13.10

Already tried cleaning the existing tomcat projects, but the issue is still not solved.

What should I do to resolve this type of error.

this is my first experience with WebSockets

Comment: And what is happening when you change your endpoint path name?

Comment: still same error, reporting error of previous endpoint

Comment: Do yuo found solution?